# Django Ignoring invalid foreign key with migrate?

Tags: python, django

When I do the migrate I get the below error. can I ignore it to continue the migration.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'pages_dataupload' with primary key '15734098' 
has an invalid foreign key: pages_dataupload.Customer_Address_id contains a value '' that 
doesn't have corresponding value in pages_bo
```

Comment: Can you add the before and after for your model to the question? If the value is invalid what do you want to do with the row?

Comment: I didn't change anything in this model I don't know what is wrong with the values. I just added another model and got this error

Comment: Also I don't need this field anymore but when I delete it I get the same error

Comment: add some more code, like the models you created.

Comment: It seems like `Customer_Address` `ForeignKey` value in " "(null). Assign the object before doing the migrations. make sure, that no record in the `pages_dataupload` model has a null foreign key.